# How to Keep a Ratchet WebSocket alive?

Tags: php, websocket, real-time, ratchet, phpwebsocket

I have a Ratchet (PHP Real-Time Class) project on my localhost. When I want to use and test this project,
I run CMD and use this command: `C:\wamp\www\ChatApp> php cmd.php` (cmd.php is websocket launcher).
and when i press `Ctrl + C` or exit cmd, this websocket dies.

but, what can i do when i transfer project to main host to alive this websocket?

cmd.php:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
require 'Chat.php';

$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new \ChatApp\Chat()
        )
    ), 8080
);

$server->run();


$server = IoServer::factory(
    new HttpServer(
        new WsServer(
            new Chat()
        )
    ), 8080
);

$server->run();
```

Chat.php (Class):

```
namespace ChatApp;

use Ratchet\MessageComponentInterface;
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;

class Chat implements MessageComponentInterface {
    protected $clients;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->clients = new \SplObjectStorage();
    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        $this->clients->attach($conn);
        echo 'Someone Connected'.PHP_EOL;
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from,$msg) {
        foreach ($this->clients as $client) {
            if ($from !== $client) {
                $client->send($msg);
            }
        }
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn){
        $this->clients->detach($conn);
        echo 'Someone Has Disconnected'.PHP_EOL;
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
        echo "An Error Has Occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
        $conn->close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ( nohup ) command in linux . Write this code in your server.php root

nohup php server.php

Comment: Please improve you answer by [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) it. If possible, add links to further reading, such as documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ( nohup ) command in linux .
Write this code in your server.php root

```
nohup php server.php &
```

To learn more about this command , [browse this link](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/unohup.htm)